# Do I need a visa for a connecting flight to Japan?

Tags: visas, airports, japan, layovers, connecting-flights

I'm going to the Philippines this October and would like to layover in Japan. I found a reasonably priced ticket with a 15-hour layover to Haneda, however, I have to transfer to Narita. Do I need a visa since I'm going to have to stay at a hotel and ride a bus to travel to Narita airport? Thank you!

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: Did you take this flight? Did they ask for visa?i will be travelling on Jan 17, 2020 using this route and appreciate if you can share the info Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Because your connecting flight is the next day and you are changing from HND to NRT, you can get a Shore Pass from Japan immigration on arrival.

Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents, states in relevant part:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>
> - Passengers with a passport and a confirmed onward ticket to a third country within 72 hours can obtain a Shore Pass on arrival if there are no connecting flights on the same calendar day. They must:
>
>   - have documents required for the next destination; and
>   - have proof of sufficient funds to cover their stay; and
>   - arrive at and depart from an airport or seaport located within the same group below.
>   - Group A:
>       Airports: Narita (NRT), Haneda (HND), Nagoya (NGO), Niigata
>       (KIJ), Komatsu (KMQ) and Yokota (OKO).
>       Seaports: Tokyo, Yokohama, Niigata and Nagoya.

Timatic doesn't mention it, but [the actual Japanese law](http://www.japaneselawtranslation.go.jp/law/detail_main?re=02&vm=&id=1934#ja_ch3sc4at2) also suggests that they may require you to have a biometric passport.