# Are all inbound international passengers routed to the same customs hall at Newark Liberty International?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airports, ewr

Newark Liberty International has 3 terminals, all 3 terminals service inbound international flights.   Are all inbound international passengers routed to the same customs hall (service area) or is there more than one hall?

Comment: I'm not so sure that Terminal A has international arrivals (other than preclearance).

Answer (score 16):

Only Terminals B and C have immigration facilities; they are separate from each other. Arrivals in Terminal B clear immigration in Terminal B, and arrivals in Terminal C clear immigration in Terminal C.

There is no immigration facility in Terminal A. Only international flights which went through US preclearance (and domestic flights) arrive at this terminal.

Comment: @michaelhamptom Is there reference \ link?   Much appreciated: thanks

Comment: @gatorback Besides the airport maps, you can look at CBP's [airport wait times](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/133827/do-i-need-a-visa-for-a-connecting-flight-to-japan) list, which shows every port of entry where they have immigration.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I think your link is wrong. That goes to a question about visas in Japan

Comment: @MatthewFitzGerald-Chamberlain Ha, you're right. That's what I get for answering many questions at once and not watching what I copy and paste. The correct link is https://awt.cbp.gov/